# Parts of pages not indexing on Google

Tags: seo, migration

I have a site I'm in the process of migrating and remaking from the old site at a new address:

[healthstart.nz](http://healthstart.nz)

The old site is still up at the old address, so I would expect that there would be duplicate content issues. I hope to resolve this by cloning and redirecting the new site & address back to the old address:

healthproducts . co . nz  (not able to link this yet, as I am new here, but I figured it may be helpful here for reference)

I've found that, while Google has crawled the new site, the results for many of the pages seem to have picked up only the text from the header and the footer, and not the main content:

[Google site search - "site:healthstart.nz"](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=site%3Ahealthstart.nz&oq=site%3Ahealthstart.nz&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.4681j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)

I'm aware that duplicate content can cause some pages to be not indexed, but is that the reason for them being partially indexed as above (without the main content)? And would this be resolved upon cloning/redirection back to the original address?

Comment: The links you provided show us the same thing... an advert for the site.

Comment: After a bit of research, I believe you meant no harm but had made links that do not give us the same results you expected. Both links provided a page for the link site and advertising and not anything related to your site - unless that is your site in which case, that is not permitted here. Please clarify or try again with another method. Cheers!!

Comment: For the record, duplicate content will exclude a page and not parts of a page. You have something else going on.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware the links included advertising. It never showed on mine, perhaps because I'm using ad' blockers. I've posted the original URL's now.

Comment: "duplicate content will exclude a page and not parts of a page."

I thought so. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna clear the confusion.

You have an old site you want to spruce up and get indexed and then you want to host it at a new address.

Your best bet is to simply issue permanent redirects from the old page to the new one. This can be done many ways. If your old server runs on apache with mod_rewrite installed, you can use .htaccess with the following contents (provided the difference between the new urls and old urls are only the domain name):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oldurl\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newurl.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Simply replace oldurl with the old domain name without the www and com, and replace newurl the same way with the new domain. For example, if your old domain name is example.com and your new one is example2.com, then you would use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The RewriteCond is optional if the new server does not host the old domain name, but it is mandatory if both domains are managed on the same server and you're just moving website contents from folder to folder.

As for what is displayed in google, just make sure you create an excellent title (put rich content that is between roughly 40 and 65 characters between `<title>` and `</title>` in your html). Also, add a good description thats between roughly 100 and 150 characters in your meta tag like so:

```
<meta name="description" content="whatever">
```

Of course, replace "whatever" with the content you expect search engines to display. In the tag, the content must be quoted as shown, but the search engines will remove the quotes for you when they index the page.

Just make sure you don't use keyword stuffing in the title or content or you might not get your pages indexed.

Comment: Thanks. I'd prefer it if the old URL could be kept. Is there a reason why you'd recommend using the new URL instead?

Comment: @Tim do you have a specific reason for keeping the old URL? For SEO, you would generally 301 redirect an old domain to a new domain to transfer any authority you've gained on the old domain.

Comment: @NickolasBurr, the new URL is being used as a development URL at a client's request. We'd like to use the old/original address to replace the original site.

Comment: @Tim That makes sense but I guess I'm just not understanding why you'd want to index a website that's under development at a temporary URL? Or was this simply an oversight that you're trying to rectify?

Comment: @NickolasBurr, I didn't realise at the time that it was going to be temporary. It was the address given by the client.

Comment: @Tim, Ah okay. Well, for future reference, best practice is to prevent any under development websites from being crawled by adding a `Disallow: /` to the robots.txt file or adding a `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">` to the head section of each applicable page (or to the header partial if you're using a CMS like WordPress) until the development process is complete.

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing is less duplicate content and more bad content. Here is how you fix this:

Google for your sites address. site:someurlhere.com

Then you will see the index for the DC that is closest to you. You can try applying the filters to find the date range around corrections and bad content.

Once you find a page, click the "cached" to see the version google thinks exists.

Make a list of these pages (your url, not googles cached url)

Log into WMT. Click on fetch as google. Enter your URL. Click "fetch and render"

After it grabs a new copy, check it on the rendered page. Look correct? Go back to the list of fetch as google URLS that you have. CLICK SUBMIT TO INDEX. Chose to only use that URL and not crawl linked pages.

I would only submit the offending URL. 500 for single url/month vs 10 for crawl linked/month.

Rinse and repeat. You can do this 500 times per month.

Comment: I am not sure abusing the kindness of Google is such a good idea.

Comment: Can you please define "DC"? I'm not sure if I understand your instructions, but I did "fetch and render" a page, and it seemed to display fine, which is all the more puzzling.

Comment: The Fetch and Render SHOULD look right! It just pulled that from your current website. DC stands for Data Center. They have indexes in each DC so you may not get the same results if you run an index:sitename.com twice. Just an FYI so you can hunt down all the rouge copies to fix. Disreguard the comment above on abusing the kindness of google. This is what this tool is designed for.

Comment: Wow. -1 huh. Fear of google is common among Owners of websites, this is a stack for webmasters. As a professional webmaster I do this every day and have for 13 years. This is the correct answer.

Comment: What sort of bad content are we talking about? I did wonder if the amount of nesting was too much for it - it's using a couple of visual layout editors.

Comment: bad content = "results for many of the pages seem to have picked up only the text from the header and the footer, and not the main content" so if those pages are "cached" by google looking like that, then that is how google "sees" those pages. They probably had been crawled during development of the site. A recrawl on those pages will fix this issue.

Comment: @user1669039, the cached pages show the full content. It was migrated to the URL more or less fully developed. It's puzzling.